# Unable to run python gstreamer script without sudo

Tags: python, gstreamer, sudo

I would like to know if someone can answer why I cant seem to get a python gstreamer pipline to work without sudo in linux. I have a very small gstreamer pipline and it fails to open the gstreamer if I dont run with sudo infront of python.
I have soon depleted my options, any help would be appriciated. (Using Jetson Orin and ubuntu 20.05)

```
import sys
import cv2

def read_cam():
    G_STREAM_TO_SCREEN = "videotestsrc num-buffers=50 ! videoconvert ! appsink"
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(G_STREAM_TO_SCREEN, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
    if cap.isOpened():
        cv2.namedWindow("demo", cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
        while True:
            ret_val, img = cap.read()
            cv2.imshow('demo',img)
            cv2.waitKey(1)
    else:
     print ("camera open failed")

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    read_cam()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely OK, since vp devices owned by root user.

What you can do is to create new group, add current user to it, change group of vp devices to the new one & grant rw permissions.

Comment: Nope. Its not ok since I have not needed it other machines to access the webcam. Also I have added the user to the video-group. Still no change. To solve it I reinstalled the computer and now it works. Must have been a library that was faulty or installed on sudo instead of user or something. This solution though might be for others!

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall your computer and be thorough with your installations….